# How do I make a floating indicator appear at the bottom right corner of a listView?

Tags: android, android-layout

**How do I make a floating indicator appear at the bottom right corner of a listView?**

For some reason the code below has the floating indication appear or the top left corner of the listView.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_general"/>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/contacts_list_view" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use alignParentRight and alignParentBottom

Comment: use android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with gravity  property you used in floatingActionButton...
android:gravity sets the gravity of the content within the View not the View itself.
instead...you should use alignParentBottom and alignParentRight properties to get desired result...
like this...

`<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />`

hope this help...

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar_general"/>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/contacts_list_view" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</RelativeLayout>
```